# Valid URL-string as NSUrl becomes null

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

another issue where I seem to have found an solution for ObjC but not MonoTouch.

I want a NSUrl from an URL (as string).

The string may contain whitespace and backslashes.

Why is NSUrl returning null for such string, even though these are valid urls in a browser?

For example:
NSUrl foo = NSUrl.FromString(@"http://google.com/search?\query");

foo == null

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post more code? What you have above looks absolutely fine.

Comment: @Mike - if you got my answer correct, please accept it.

Answer (score 13):

[NSURL URLWithString:[googlSearchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Referenced by
[Stack Overflow....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125230/nsurl-urlwithstring-is-null-with-non-english-accented-characters)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to process the string first with

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
```

... so that it can be processed a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

URLWithString:
Creates and returns an NSURL object initialized with a provided string.

- (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString
  Parameters
  URLString
  The string with which to initialize the NSURL object. Must be a URL that conforms to RFC 2396. This method parses URLString according to RFCs 1738 and 1808. (To create NSURL objects for file system paths, use fileURLWithPath:isDirectory: instead.)
  Return Value
  An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the string was malformed, returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

`NSString * urlString = @"http://example/newcase/path/fileNames";
    urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);`