# [NSURL URLWithString:stringContainingSpecialCharacters]

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsurl

Say, I have an address bar which is a UITextField called textField, and a UIWebView named webView. Most of the time the follow code works:

```
[webView loadURL:[NSURL URLWithString:textField.text]];
```

When I put in some long string with special characters, `URLWithString:` simply returns `null`. The Readability bookmarklet is a good example:

```
javascript:(function(){readConvertLinksToFootnotes=true;readStyle='style-newspaper';readSize='size-medium';readMargin='margin-wide';_readability_script=document.createElement('script');_readability_script.type='text/javascript';_readability_script.src='http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/js/readability.js?x='+(Math.random());document.documentElement.appendChild(_readability_script);_readability_css=document.createElement('link');_readability_css.rel='stylesheet';_readability_css.href='http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/css/readability.css';_readability_css.type='text/css';_readability_css.media='all';document.documentElement.appendChild(_readability_css);_readability_print_css=document.createElement('link');_readability_print_css.rel='stylesheet';_readability_print_css.href='http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/css/readability-print.css';_readability_print_css.media='print';_readability_print_css.type='text/css';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_readability_print_css);})();
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125230/nsurl-urlwithstring-is-null-with-non-english-accented-characters/2125247#2125247), I can use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` to escape the string, and indeed it works fine for this case.

My question is: **Is this safe to always call `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` before passing the string to the webView? Does the following have any consequences?**

```
[webView loadURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[textField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]
```

Thanks!

EDIT: What I mean by 'safe' is that while this works with URLs containing Unicode characters, does it still work fine with 'normal' URLs?

EDIT 2: If this is 'safe', why isn't it the default behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there's no other answers to my question, I decided to use the following `- (NSURL *)URLValue` method instead of `- (NSURL *)URLWithString:` as a safe measure:

```
- (NSURL *)URLValue {
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:self];

    if (URL) return URL;

    return [NSURL URLWithString:[self stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

Comment: you found the right way to do it because if you have `NSString *str = @"http://example.com/日本語;` and do: `[NSURL URLWithString:]` returns `nil`. However it you do `[NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]` it correctly returns: `http://example.com/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E`

Answer (score 0):

No problems. All the returned objects are autoreleased, so no leaks.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not concerned about the memory management aspect —  What I mean by 'safe' is that while this works with URLs containing Unicode characters, does it still work fine with 'normal' URLs?

Comment: Then why isn't it the default behaviour?