# I couldn't send a request with Arabic letters in the URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, url

I'm developing an iPhone app that takes advantage of Google search api and search through Arabic content.

Whenever I send a request that includes arabic letters in the URL to get a JSON file format I get error message indicates that the request has failed. this is what  the request looks like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?oe=utf-8&ie= ISO-8859-6&key=[MY KEY]&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=جوجل&alt=json
```

This is the method in my code that invokes the request and retrieves the data:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?oe=utf-8&ie= ISO-8859-6&key=[MY KEY]&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=جوجل&alt=json"]] delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use percent-encoding in the URLs to make things work as you cannot just pass any arbitrary string in a URL. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125230/nsurl-urlwithstring-is-null-with-non-english-accented-characters) for more information. Basically, it boils down to running your string through the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method. Since this method supports UTF-8 encoding only, you'll also have to pass `ie=utf-8` in the URL instead of `ie=ISO-8859-6`.

Comment: Work like a charm! thanks, that what at least i can do four you, of course beside marking you answer as the solution. here is what i did:  NSString *search = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?ie=utf8&key=AIzaSyDVyDpALRofi3swJdMPZErNo8kVhlDOpek&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=%@&alt=json",string ];                    
url = [NSURL URLWithString:[search stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];