# NSURLRequest - Request a url with more than 300 characters

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to perform the below request

```
NSString* testString = @"http://www.abcd.com?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx........." (The length of testString is more than 400 characters)
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:testString]];
```

If i try the above snippet the urlRequest is sending as a NULL value. Is there any possibility to compress the string or URL???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limitation about NSString length to pass to URL, but there are special chars can do it, for example, space, accents and others.

Try it:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[testString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// if it`s using utf8
```

There is more details in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125230/nsurl-urlwithstring-is-null-with-non-english-accented-characters)