# Image at URL failing to populate NSData

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nsurl, nsimage

I have an image at a URL which is failing to load into an NSData.

When I paste the image URL into a Chrome incognito window, it displays successfully.

However, the following fails:

```
photoData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoUrl]];
NSLog(@"data: %@", photoData);
```

The NSLog outputs:

```
data: (null)
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'd appreciate any advice, thanks.

Edit: The URL has extended ASCII characters in it, such as à.

Comment: Did you put the `http://` part before your url ?

Comment: Yes, the value of `photoUrl` is `@"http://..."`

Comment: The URL has extended ASCII characters in it, such as à. Does that matter?

Comment: Yes that would matter. Try to escape the url before passing it to your `NSURL` object: `[photoUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Comment: Thanks, submitted the answer to my own question below. If it's possible to do so, you can try submitting this as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh. Found the answer. Needed to escape the URL for extended ASCII. Need to add:

```
photoUrl = [photoUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2125247/870345). Thanks!