# NSMUtableURLRequest requestWithURL returns null whenever URL contains Japanese parameters

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

Whenever the URL contains Japanese Parameters, `requestWithURL` function returns `null`.

```
urlString = https://translate.google.co.in/#ja/en/はははは
NSMutableURLRequest *Request= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Whenever the Parameters include EN, requestWithURL works fine.

Comment: I tried your code (in swift). The URL itself becomes `nil` when you create it from that string. The request comes as `nil` simply because you are passing a `nil` URL to begin with.

Comment: I am not very versed in the intricacies `NSURL` class, but perhaps you should sanitize your string somehow before trying to create a URL from non-ascii characters. Not sure, but a thorough read of the docs could give you a clue...

Comment: I found your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125230/nsurl-urlwithstring-is-null-with-non-english-accented-characters

Comment: Thanks Nicolas but the problem still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode your path, since it contains characters not allowed in an URL:

```
NSString *base = @"https://translate.google.co.in";
NSString *path = @"/#ja/en/はははは";

NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:base];
urlComponents.path = path;

NSMutableURLRequest *request= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlComponents.URL];
```

Note that the request still won't give you the desired result, since in a browser you do a request to `https://translate.google.co.in/` with `ja/en/はははは` as a [fragment identifier for JavaScript](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs), while in the code you make an request to `https://translate.google.co.in/#`..., which doesn't exist.