# How to set a Japanese URL in webView (macOS)

Tags: macos, cocoa, uiwebview, webkit

I am using webview in my cocoa app. In my URL i have some Japanese chars, web page is not loading. For same resource if i change name in english it is working.

Here is the not-working code:
[webView setMainFrameURL:@"[http://localhost:8080/引き割り.png](http://localhost:8080/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D%E5%89%B2%E3%82%8A.png)"];

Working code :
[webView setMainFrameURL:@"http://localhost:8080/1234.png"];

Comment: Might have to do what is done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125230/nsurl-urlwithstring-is-null-with-non-english-accented-characters

Comment: I have tried as suggested above, but no success.